# How to open Excel File on Sharepoint with a Wildcard using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I trying to open a excel file stored in a Sharepoint (HTTPS), from excel VBA. The problem is than the file name change every day, so I trying to use a wildcard to open it without sucess. If I put the full name of archive I can open it. 
Here my code:

```
sub abrir()

Dim xlFile As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

xlFile = "https://xxxxxx.sharepoint.com/:x:/x/xxxxx/xxxxxxx/xxxxxx/xxxxxxx/xxxxxxx/xxxxx/excel file" & "*.xlsx"

Workbooks.Open xlFile

end sub
```

Comment: Anybody can help?